# htaccess rewriterule not working if multiple levels

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a problem with my htaccess rule.
I am using Wordpress and in my htaccess there is nothing except the default wordpress code.

I have this rewrite rule working:

```
RewriteRule aa/bb http://www.example.com?catID=id1&prodID=id2
```

It shows aa/bb in the address bar and shows me the content of http://www.example.com?catID=id1&prodID=id2

When I add another level, it doesn't work, for example:

```
RewriteRule aa/bb/cc http://www.example.com?catID=id1&prodID=id2
```

How can I solve this and add as many levels as I want?